# differential equation..part of the integral in the answer

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing a differential equation and part of the integral in the answer I don't understand. Where did the `e^​t` go from the top when they were integrating ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=e^t+1$. Then, $du=d(e^t+1)=d(e^t)=e^tdt$. So, in the integral, when you have $e^tdt$, you can substitute...

Comment: wait that was u-substitution ?

Comment: @manual I guess - I'm a self-learner, so I'm not really familiar with all the commonly-used terms (I'm 13).